# Get exact match with LIKE - SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

Given the text:

```
"Hello, I'm from Hell",
"Hello, I'm from Ell"
```

and the following SQL clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text LIKE '%ell%'
```

I get both the texts above, but I don't want to get both texts, because I was looking for the text
"Ell" and not "Hell"

If anyone knows what I mean, can you help me out?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

BETTER EXAMPLE

Like when you want to look for the word 'big' but it can't be part of any other word like 'bigger' or 'biggest'

Comment: you might have to use regular expression

Comment: You mean that you want to execute your like statement with case sensitive ?

Comment: Nope not case sensitive. I want to search for the seperate word "ell". I don't want to get a return hell, because ell is part of hell, if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the MySQL Regex word boundary matching:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text REGEXP '[[:<:]]ell[[:>:]]'
```

This matches a string which cosntains the word `ell` with a word boundary on either side.

Comment: Did you test the regexp with text with multi-line such as 
'123
hell
hellhell'?
If the "text" field format in multi line text, and use the above statement, it still shows result while it should not

Comment: This was too slow for my use case

Comment: @duhaime If this is too slow for you, you probably want to build a table for indexing by tokens. Every time you insert, update, or delete from your table storing the text blobs, you have to update the index, but that will be fast. Only the initial creation of the index will be slow.

Comment: @Paulpro Can you please explain above query ? What is the meaning of brackets, colon sign here. and how it works. ? For ex. I have large database  lets say more 100,000. and but i have only some starting character of column value and some last chars .. so how this query will be applicable .. suppose i have to search by sku i.e . 12345678-abc-pqr-123  and I hae only some starting digit and some last characters for ex. pqr-123. can you please explain for it.

Comment: @RahulDambare Th `[[:<:]]` matches the start of a word and the other one matches the end of a word. Those were only useful because the column contained a string with multiple word tokens in it. I don't think those will be useful for your case, something like `WHERE sku LIKE '1%pqr-123'` should be useful though.

Answer (score 1):

Can you search for a space as well?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE text LIKE '% ell%'
OR text LIKE 'ell%' // needed if string starts with ell
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text LIKE BINARY '%ell%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the exactly match no case sensitive

SELECT * FROM table
 where LOWER(column) like BINARY LOWER('ell')

It works if the text has multi-line.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use REGEXP in the query. have a look a this resource which contains all the detail you need.

syntax is simple as follows

```
$sql= "select * from post where title REGEXP '$s'";
```